# Google federated login/openId redirect

Tags: authentication, openid

This is from the [google federated login description](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID)

"Once Google accepts the authentication request, the user is redirected to a Google authentication page. At this point the authentication sequence takes over. On successful authentication, Google redirects the user back to the URL specified in the openid.return_to parameter of the original request."

I assume my web app is responsible for the redirect 'to a Google authentication page' mentioned here? I dont see how google can make this redirect.
And If my webapp does the redirect, how do the openid request parameters get sent to google?

Answer (score 0):

On reading some more, its only possible that once "[Once Google accepts the authentication request](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#Response)", (I assume the requesting party gets a 200 http status), the requesting web application now adds the same parameters that had been posted to google login endpoint to a google authentication url and then redirects the user to this url